# How to load internally stored data before functions in an R package?

Tags: r, package, devtools, roxygen2

I am currently writing an R package containing project-specific data cleaning functions for my collaborators, using devtools and roxygen2 and following the RStudio suggested formats. Many of these functions essentially fix typos/common data entry errors using reference files (dataframes) that are currently stored in the package's sysdata.rda file under /R. Prior to the issue I present below, referencing the files and using them within functions was working fine. Lazy load is set to true.

I would like to make a function that allows users to add a row to these reference files if they come across a novel typo/error. From my research and from reading the very helpful information at https://r-pkgs.org/data.html, it seems the best way to do this is to list the reference files to a new environment, and then allow the user to edit those files within the session-specific environment. Ideally, these changes would persist across sessions but I cannot figure out how to make that work so am continuing down this path.

For brevity, I've only included one of these files, called column_standardized, that contains standard names for the columns as well as the potential alternatives we regularly come across. A function called "standardize.columns" coerces column names of input data frames to the standards and reorders them also to our agreed standard.

Here is a short reproducible of the column_standardized:

```
column_standardized <- data.frame(standard_name = c("date", "date", "time", "ID", "ID", "ID", "location", "location"), other_names = c("DATE", "day", "TIME", "id", "individual", "name", "LOCATION", "locale"))
```

To do this, I created a file in /R that contains the following code, based heavily on the example in https://r-pkgs.org/data.html (section 8.5, Internal State). The file is titled "aaaaa.R" so it comes before other functions in /R:
(The reason I set key, correct_col, and alt_col are so that the same function can act upon different reference files with the same code. It works fine and I am not necessarily seeking feedback on the data manipulation aspects of this function.)

```
the <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
the$column_standardized <- column_standardized

#' Add alternative names to reference
#'
#' @param correct A character string of the standard/correct name
#' @param alt A character string of the alternative name
#' @param data_type A character string indicating which reference file to edit. Options are 'column' (and others in reality).
#'
#' @return NA; edits included reference files for current R session.
#' @export
add.alt <- function(correct, alt, data_type){
  if(data_type == "column"){
    key <- the$column_standardized
    correct_col <- "standard_name"
    alt_col <- "other_names"
  }else{print("\nData type not found. Acceptable options are 'column', etc.")}
  new_key <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(colnames(key)), nrow = 1))
  colnames(new_key) <- colnames(key)
  new_key[1,correct_col] <- correct
  new_key[1, alt_col] <- alt
  key <- rbind(key, new_key)
  if(data_type == "column"){
    the$column_standardized <- key
    invisible(key)
  }}
```

No errors/issues are flagged when I run document() or load_all(), but when I check the package it is unable to install because column_standardized does not exist. I assume this is because sysdata.rda is loaded after .R files in /R.

I have also tried to put column_standardized in the /data folder and call it using system.file but run into the same error.

The actual file is over 300 rows long, and there are multiple reference files, and so I don't think it makes sense to just recreate the data frame in the environment from scratch, although I've considered it.

Finally, to my specific questions:

1. Is there a way to load the system data first so that .R files in /R can reference the data included?

- I am not wed to storing them internally although that would be ideal for privacy reasons, and could move the dataframes to /data or another location. This seemed initially simplest but I could be wrong.

2. Is there a modification that would allow each user to "permanently" modify these reference files? It wouldn't be too much of a headache for them to run add.alt() each session since the files already contain most common errors, and once user data is edited/standardized one usually does not need to restandardize in another session. If someone knows a solution, however, it would probably be the ideal.

I am potentially completely off-base here as this is my first time developing a package, so any tips are appreciated! Many thanks in advance, and happy to provide more documentation information if I've forgotten anything crucial.

Comment: I think it is likely to be a bad idea to try to store changeable data within the package.  It's better to store it outside of R.  This blog post https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/03/persistent-config-and-data-for-r-packages/ describes some ways to do that.

Comment: This seems promising, thanks! I’ll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across this issue/wants to include editable data within R packages in this way, I've detailed my fix to the issue below. Many thanks to the commenter above for linking to that helpful blog.

All reference files are stored in the sysdata.Rda file in /R. Two functions in the package write the baseline reference files to the user's R data cache and draw the files from that cache upon each new R session.

Upon installation, the user is directed to run save.reference(dir.create = TRUE) to write all reference files to their user cache:

```
function (file = "all", dir.create = FALSE) 
{
    if (dir.create == TRUE) {
        dir.create(tools::R_user_dir("packagename", which = "cache"), 
            recursive = TRUE)
    }
    path <- paste(tools::R_user_dir("packagename", which = "cache"))
    if (file == "all") {
        file <- c("file 1", "file 2", 
            "file 3", "etc")
    }
    for (filename in file) {
        utils::write.csv(get(filename), paste(path, "/", filename, 
            ".csv", sep = ""), row.names = FALSE)
    }
}
```

Then, load.reference() reads any or all reference files from the cache into the current R environment:

```
function (file = "all") 
{
    path <- paste(tools::R_user_dir("packagename", which = "cache"))
    if (file == "all") {
        file <- c("file 1", "file 2", 
            "file 3", "etc")
    }
    for (filename in file) {
        temp <- utils::read.csv(paste(path, "/", filename, ".csv", 
            sep = ""))
        print2envlist <- list(temp = temp)
        names(print2envlist)[1] <- filename
        list2env(print2envlist, .GlobalEnv)
    }
}
```

Any changes made during the R session can be saved before quitting by running save.reference(). If long-term, user-wide changes are needed to any reference files, they can be included in package updates and then user files can be overwritten by running save.reference(dir.create = TRUE) again. The user can also access the files in their file explorer at the cache location and edit them in any other programs.

I hope this helps if anyone else finds themself in the same situation!